# ssh: too many connections in short succession?

Tags: ssh, sshd

I'm running a backup server using `rsnapshot`, which uses `rsync`, which uses `ssh` to connect to the hosts from which to gather data. Usually, everything works fine. I run in to issues, however, if very little data has changed, and if there are a lot of separate directories to be backed up (more than 5).
I figured out that the issue is `ssh`, which can only connect five times within roughly minute, then I have to wait again before making another attempt. This script demonstrates the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

for j in {1..3}
do
    for i in {1..6}
    do
        ssh my.server.xyz 'exit' && echo "ok #${i}" || echo "failed #${i}"
    done
    sleep 60
done
```

The output looks as follows:

```
ok #1
ok #2
ok #3
ok #4
ok #5
ssh: connect to host my.server.xyz port 22: Connection refused
failed #6
ok #1
ok #2
ok #3
ok #4
ok #5
ssh: connect to host my.server.xyz port 22: Connection refused
failed #6
ok #1
ok #2
ok #3
ok #4
ok #5
ssh: connect to host my.server.xyz port 22: Connection refused
failed #6
```

Is there some `sshd` option to configure this limit of 10? I'd like to be able to do up to 10 connections from the same host within a couple of seconds.

Comment: `Connection refused` may be because of some firewall or whatever. In SSH there is connection sharing. I guess `ssh -M` may be a client-side solution. See `man 1 ssh`. You will also need the `-S` option of `ssh` and the `-e` option of `rsync`. Alternatively configure your `ssh` [like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33581/108618), start the first connection manually (`ssh -N` maybe) and let any number of later connections use it automatically. Untested, therefore just a comment, not a proper answer. If it works for you then feel free to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, it really was the Firewall (IP Tables).

Comment: OK, theoretically if the culprit is like in your answer then my client-side solution should work. It's most useful for people who are not in charge of the firewall. I also noticed [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33557/108618#comment508540_33581) which seems to match your case perfectly and removes the need of manual connection.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that it has not really anything to do with `ssh`, but with IP tables on the server (where `sshd` runs):

```
# iptables -S | grep 22
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 6 --name DEFAULT --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j ufw-user-limit
```